# I'm learning R. I was wondering how I could make a barplot with a data set I've made?

Tags: r, graphics, bar-chart

Here is the data I've made:

```
    structure(list(Resort = c("Park City", "Powder Mountain", "Snowbird", 
    "Alta", "Snow Basin", "Deer Valley"), `Named Runs` = c(348, 154, 
    140, 116, 107, 103)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df",
```

"tbl", "data.frame"))

Here is my code. I'm trying to get a bar graph, with resorts on the x-axis and named runs on the y-axis. Unfortunately, my graph is only showing resorts. How can I fix this? Thanks.

```
    library(readxl)
    Utah_ski_resort_data_ <- read_excel("Desktop/Utah ski resort data..xlsx")    
    View(Utah_ski_resort_data_)
    table(Utah_ski_resort_data_$Resort)
    table(Utah_ski_resort_data_$`Named Runs`)
    barplot(table(Utah_ski_resort_data_$Resort)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what is wrong when we can't see your data or the errors you are getting, but generally `:` is a special character and isn't allowed in standard column names, so any time you use `$Resort:` that will be a syntax error. I'd suggest cleaning the column names so you can use standard R syntax with them. You can do that with `names(Utah_ski_resort_data_) <- make.names(names(Utah_ski_resort_data_))`.

Comment: If you need more help than that, please post a little sample data, e.g., `dput(Utah_ski_resort_data_[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows, and also post the first error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`barplot` with formula:

```r
barplot(`Named Runs` ~ Resort, Utah_ski_resort_data_)
```

And this is a `ggplot2` barplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
Utah_ski_resort_data_ %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Resort, y = `Named Runs`)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```